webpack css loaders working on windows powershel but dont in linux bash
I have a webpack setup that works properly in Windows powershell,
But when trying to build the same in Linux console
It seems that the css loaders are not working properly
However, I'm not sure where to look.
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
    poll: 1000, // Check for changes every second
  },
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 1024000,
    maxAssetSize: 1024000
  },

  entry:{
    slick_style:'./node_modules/slick-slider/slick/slick.scss',
    sass_embeded:'./src/js/home.js',
  },
  output:{
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, '../site/'),
    filename:'js/[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename:'js/[name].bundle.[id].js',
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jquery',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      linkType: "text/css",
      filename: 'css/[name].bundle.css',
      chunkFilename: "css/[name].bundle.[id].css",
    }),
    new MomentLocalesPlugin(),
    new MomentLocalesPlugin({
      localesToKeep: ['es-us'],
    }),

  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // 'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false,
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              // Prefer `dart-sass`
              implementation: require("sass"),
              sourceMap: true,
              // sourceMapContents: false,
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/site/'),
      },
    ],
  },
}

and my output looks like the picture

is there a practice of webpack config for windows and linux
or something i'm missing in this config

thanks a lot for your time every one
i found the problem
i just remove the last
include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/site/'),

So everything worked on Linux.
I'm not sure if Windows just ignored the "include", but it seems like Linux has problems with this.
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
      // 'style-loader',
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          url: false,
          // sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          // Prefer `dart-sass`
          implementation: require("sass"),
          sourceMap: true,
          // sourceMapContents: false,
          sassOptions: {
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
],
},

